# Join two queries mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to join two queries :

This first query get "pgm_posts.post_title" and "pgm_post_views.count" (WHERE  pgm_post_views.type="4")

[image: pgm_posts TABLE]

```
SELECT pgm_posts.post_title, pgm_post_views.count
FROM pgm_posts, pgm_post_views
WHERE  pgm_post_views.type="4" AND pgm_post_views.id = pgm_posts.id
```

This second query get all the ids from "pgm_post_views" with condition.

pgm_post_views.type="0" : its the condition for get "period". (look img)

[image: pgm_post_views TABLE]

```
SELECT pgm_posts.id
FROM pgm_posts
INNER JOIN pgm_post_views
ON pgm_posts.id = pgm_post_views.id AND pgm_post_views.type="0" AND DATE_FORMAT(pgm_post_views.period, "%Y-%m-%d") <= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(pgm_posts.post_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <= DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Resume : First query get post_title and total count based on all ids of second query.

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is a pure join based on selected table

```
SELECT p
        gm_posts.post_title
      , pgm_post_views.count
FROM pgm_posts 
INNER JOIN  pgm_post_views ON  pgm_post_views.id = pgm_posts.id 
                  AND pgm_post_views.type="4"
INNER JOIN ( 
 SELECT 
        pgm_posts.id
 FROM pgm_posts
 INNER JOIN pgm_post_views ON pgm_posts.id = pgm_post_views.id AND pgm_post_views.type="0" 
          AND DATE_FORMAT(pgm_post_views.period, "%Y-%m-%d") <= 
                        DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d') 
          AND DATE_FORMAT(pgm_posts.post_date, "%Y-%m-%d") <= 
                        DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d')
) T on T.id = pgm_posts
```

Comment: Thx for help,  i understand now how i can for others queries ! Thx